# Haskell, WinX: UTF8 stdin causes problems

Tags: windows, haskell, utf-8

I use windows 10 and powershell, it seems that Haskell have some issues with UTF encoding from stdin:

```
> chcp 65001
> stack ghci
...

> putStrLn "자"
자

> x <- getLine
자
> x
"\EOT"

> interact id
자
╝
```

Comment: @DanielSanchez `\EOT` is end-of-transmission, an ASCII control character (also called `^D` or `Control-D`, value `0x04`). It's not `자`, ___at all___. `자` is `\51088` (0xC790).

Comment: The behaviour can be reproduced in Win 8.1 using ConEmu, although you end up with a more drastic result: `getLine` will throw an exception, since the line ends prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect GHC is operating on a latin1 encoding (or similar), and `putStrLn "자"` only worked by accident. You can check this as follows:

```
> import System.IO
System.IO> hGetEncoding stdin
```

If this replies with `UTF-8` my hypothesis is wrong. But if it replies with something other than `UTF-8`, you can explicitly declare which encoding the console is expecting with `hSetEncoding`:

```
System.IO> hSetEncoding stdin utf8
```

You may also want to do this for `stdout` and `stderr`. See [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/System-IO.html) for more details.

Comment: `> hGetEncoding stdin` returns utf8... I tried `hSetEncoding stdin utf8` just to be sure but nothing changed.